# Qt и Sqlite. QSqlDatabase не найден

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt5, qsqldatabase

Есть цель подключить приложение Qt (6.3.1) к базе данных Sqlite.

```
#include <QsqlDatabase>
```

Пишет - не найден. А следующий вариант

```
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("F:\\database.db");
}
```

Дает такую ошибку - :-1: Fehler: C:/Users/ERT/Documents/myApp/mainwindow.cpp:10: undefined reference to `_*imp__ZN12QSqlDatabase11addDatabaseERK7QStringS2*'

Два дня не могу найти решение. Весь интернет переворошил. Пробовал в файле CMakeList.txt вот это, но безуспешно:

```
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Quick Sql)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}Sql REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(exulino Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Quick Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Sql)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871093/unable-to-open-sqlite-database

Comment: У меня нет  *.pro file, так как использую cmake. Туда QT += sql не впишешь.

Comment: Попробовать добавить в cmake команду для поиска sql: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38321610/5909792